# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/streams/jdk8/StreamsKt after adding Dagger Hilt to project

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, noclassdeffounderror, dagger-hilt

I recently added Dagger Hilt to my Android project and now when I run the app, I get the following error: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/streams/jdk8/StreamsKt". I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, as well as invalidating caches and restarting Android Studio, but the error persists.

I suspect that there may be some compatibility issues between Dagger Hilt and Kotlin streams, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. Has anyone else experienced this error, and if so, how did you fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the relevant part of my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44"
}


dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10"
    classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.44"
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Updating the Hilt version from `2.44` to `2.50` should solve your problem.

Comment: You might enjoy this info https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting Apart from that please try for [answer]. Especially, your post would benefit form a description of the effect of what you propose and an explanation why that helps to solve the problem.